# Need info on AFCI requirements

Tags: electrical, furnace, circuit-breaker, dryer, stove

Are AFCI breakers required on 30 amp dryer circuits and 50 amp furnace and stove circuits or just the 20 and 15's?

I haven't done residential in a long time. Thanks fellas.

Comment: Can we assume that you're talking about generic NEC 2014 or are they going to apply one of the hundreds of modified/amended versions that are randomly scattered about?

Comment: Yes. 2014.Sorry for not identifying that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're concerned with AFCI requirements in ***dwellings***, the generic National Electrical Code (NEC) 2014 edition, Section 210.12 only requires AFCI for selected "120-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere branch circuits", according to their locations.  Additional requirements may apply for plug-connected room-air conditioners (Art 440) and with interconnected power sources (Section 705.12(D)) related to utility-connected inverters.  In theory, a 230-v A/C requires "factory-installed" AFCI, if connected via plug and cord. Section 440.65.

Local codes may vary (somewhat wildly) on the requirements for any AFCI at all.

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your answer at the end. There is no 440.45 in the 2014 or 2017 NEC  it goes from 440.41 to 440.51.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Thanks. I fixed it. Yes, all refs in the answer are to 2014 edition.

Answer (score 1):

In our area, what is called the Inland NW, (eastern Washington State) what is being required in residences, (I don't think they are required at all outside of residential) all 110-volt circuits, both 15-Amp and 20-Amp circuits in new construction will be protected by AFCI.  None of the 240-volt circuits are required to be protected by arc-fault.  In remodel, if a circuit has been altered then it is required to be brought up modern standard, meaning it must be protected by AFCI.  Again the 240-volt circuits are not required to be protected by AFCI. In some jurisdictions, in 200-Amp service alterations, i.e. new panel, meter base, service raceway and service conductor, etc; as long as the panel in not moved more than 6-feet, they are not considering that as altering the 120-volt circuits.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a home flooded by hurricane harvey waters. My uncle and i are trying to make sure we comply with code.

Comment: Article 210.12 branch circuit extension or modifications. This exception is in both the 14&17 code versions. Moving an outlet 6 feet does not require a AFCI , this is a modification in fact in my state unless the entire circuit is replaced AFCI is not required.

Comment: I will be rewiring the entire house. Old cloth romex w no ground.

Comment: @EdBeal, thanks Ed. That is a good clarification that I didn't know about.  I will add that to my mental stores of electrical data.

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to do anything like that, especially in floodlands, I would want GFCI.  One thing that really struck mee during Harvey was all the 2-storey buildings where the first storey had 3 feet of water in it, but the ceiling lights were on, and the second storey was habitable.  That's because the service panel was on the 2nd floor, everything down to the first floor was on GFCI, and it just auto-tripped.

AFCI is for detecting *arcing* wiring faults.  90% of what I do is in metal conduit, where arc fault protection is pointless.  As appalling as this sounds, I feel like arc fault protection exists because of builders' fondness for cheap construction like blue plastic boxes and backstabs.  If it's practical for you to fit EMT where you are running large appliances, it takes that issue right off the table.  I would aim to slope horizontal EMT runs very slightly so it self-drains.

Comment: Service panel on 2nd floor? If a disconnect was located outside I guess but I have only seen subs above grade in residential , nothing in code that would make it wrong with an exterior disconnect.